# How to get rid of the menu bar of a custom task pane?

Tags: vsto, add-in, ctp

[image]Hello,

I have constructed a simple custom task pane for Excel, and woud like the top of the user control inside the pane to align with the top of the column headers, but there is an ugly menu bar on the top preventing it from doing so (picture attached; it is the bar with "MyCustomTaskPane" on it). Does anyone know how one would go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the properties of the Form and set the FormBorderStyle property to None.

BTW there is no image attached.

Comment: The CustomTaskPane is not a Winforms component. It looks like a native window and the interop library only exposes a few properties for it.